# What is the classic way to say that I have 3 friends females?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-order

What is the classic way to say for example that I have 3 friends females in my neighborhood?

If I'll say "I have three girlfriends" it's supposed to sound weird or polygamy. I just want to say that I have 3 friends while the listener will understand that I'm talking about female friends.

Comment: Just like you did with the last two words of your question: *female friends*.

Comment: You can say three female friends, three girl friends or  three lady friends.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the classic way to say for example that I have 3 friends females in my neighborhood?

I don't know about "classic", but the correct way is "3 female friends".  *Female* is an ordinary adjective.